# Debugging a segfault — program always does as it should but always segfaults

Tags: c, sockets, gcc, gdb, segmentation-fault

This program is supposed to print a webpage to terminal

usage: `./prog www.page.com 80 /folder/index.html`

**program always does as it should but always seg-faults at the end**

```
#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 600
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <termios.h>

#define HOST "localhost"
#define PAGE "/"
#define PORT "80"
#define USERAGENT "HTML 1.1"

char *build_get_query(char *host,char *page){
    char *query;
    char *getpage = page;
    char *tpl = "GET /%s HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: %s\r\nUser-Agent: %s\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n";

if(getpage[0]=='/'){
        getpage=getpage + 1; /*Removing leading / */
    }
    /* -5 is to consider the %s %s %s in tpl and the ending \0 */
    query=malloc(strlen(host)+strlen(getpage)+strlen(USERAGENT)+strlen(tpl)-5);
    sprintf(query, tpl, getpage, host, USERAGENT);

    return query;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    int sockfd;

    struct addrinfo hints, *servinfo, *p;
    int s;  

    char *page;
    char *stringA;
    int tmpres;
    char *sstr;

    if(argc<3){
        fprintf(stderr,"\n\tUSAGE:\n\t%s hostname/ip PORTnr /PAGE/index.shtml \n\n",argv[0]);
        fprintf(stderr,"\texample:\n\t%s www.anypage.com 80 /folder/index.shtml \n\n",argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }

    memset(&hints,0,sizeof(struct addrinfo));
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;    /* Allow IPv4 or IPv6 */
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM; /* stream socket */
    hints.ai_flags=0;
    hints.ai_protocol=0;          /* Any protocol */
    if((s=getaddrinfo(argv[1],PORT,&hints,&servinfo))!=0){
        fprintf(stderr,"\n\tgetaddrinfo: %s\n",gai_strerror(s));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    for(p=servinfo; p!=NULL; p=p->ai_next){
        if((sockfd=socket(p->ai_family,p->ai_socktype,p->ai_protocol))==-1){
            fprintf(stderr,"\n\tSOCKET FAIL\n\n");
            continue;
        }

        if((connect(sockfd,p->ai_addr,p->ai_addrlen))<0){
            close(sockfd);
            fprintf(stderr,"\n\tCONECTION FAIL\n\n");
            continue;
        }
        break;
    }
    if(p==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"\n\tCONECTION FAIL\n\n");
        exit(2);
    }
    freeaddrinfo(servinfo);


    if(argc > 3){
        page=argv[3];
    }else{
        page=PAGE;
    }

    if((stringA=malloc(BUFSIZ))==NULL){
        printf("\n\tMEMORY ERROR\n\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    stringA=build_get_query(argv[1],page);
    if((write(sockfd,stringA,strlen(stringA)))<0){
        printf("\n\tERROR ON SEND\n\n");
    }
    memset(stringA, 0, sizeof(stringA));

    while((tmpres=read(sockfd,stringA,BUFSIZ))>0){

        if((sstr=strstr(stringA,"<!DOCTYPE "))!=NULL){
            stringA=sstr;
        }
        if((sstr=strstr(stringA,"</html>"))!=NULL){
            strncpy(sstr+7,"\n",(BUFSIZ-strlen(stringA))+5);
        }
        fprintf(stdout,"%s",stringA);

    }
    if(tmpres<0){
        perror("READ ERROR");
    }

    close(sockfd);
    return 0;
}
```

**gdb info**

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:183
183 dl-fini.c: No such file or directory.
    in dl-fini.c
(gdb) bt
#0  _dl_fini () at dl-fini.c:183
#1  0x0015d1ef in __run_exit_handlers (status=0, listp=0x289324, run_list_atexit=true) at exit.c:78
#2  0x0015d25f in *__GI_exit (status=0) at exit.c:100
#3  0x00144bde in __libc_start_main (main=0x804892d <main>, argc=4, ubp_av=0xbffff454, init=0x8048d00 <__libc_csu_init>, 
    fini=0x8048cf0 <__libc_csu_fini>, rtld_fini=0x11e080 <_dl_fini>, stack_end=0xbffff44c) at libc-start.c:258
#4  0x08048811 in _start ()
(gdb)
```

I am intrigued with gdb information because I have installed `sudo apt-get install build-essential`  about a year ago and never had problems until today.

Comment: Please narrow your code down to the smallest possible example that still exhibits the error. Often, doing this results in you finding the problem on your own, but if not, it will at least make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: @elchonon-edelson considering the project i have in hands that is the smallest piece of code i could come with to debug/test/stress

Comment: `memset(stringA, 0, sizeof(stringA));` looks fishy, `stringA` is a `char*`.

Comment: @daniel-fischer corrected to `memset(stringA,0,BUFSIZ+1);`

Comment: I hope you'va also increased the argument of `malloc`, otherwise you're writing outside the allocated memory.

Comment: @daniel-fischer i did, stringA=malloc(BUFSIZ+1)

Comment: But you do the `malloc()` **before** you call `build_get_query()` which **replaces** that pointer with the one you `malloc()` for the `query` variable in that function. So, the buffer you are reading into is the length of the `query` var, not `BUFSIZ` -- again, see my latest edit to my answer for the fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing I see is that you allocate `BUFSIZ` bytes to the buffer, and you read up to `BUFSIZ` bytes into the buffer, but you are trying to use a `strstr()` and a `strlen()` on the buffer... which, if you have actually read `BUFSIZ` bytes into your buffer may well not be a null terminated string.

I would suggest you allocate `BUFSIZ+1` and `memset( stringA, 0, BUFSIZ+1 )` to guard against a random walk through memory by `strlen()` which would produce some pretty undefined behaviors in the while loop and could also result in the `printf()` within the loop behaving oddly, or at least use `printf( "%.*s", BUFSIZ, stringA );` for the output.

```
char readBuffer[BUFSIZ+1] = { 0 };

stringA=build_get_query(argv[1],page);

if((write(sockfd,stringA,strlen(stringA)))<0){
    printf("\n\tERROR ON SEND\n\n");
}

while((tmpres=read(sockfd,readBuffer,BUFSIZ))>0){

    if((sstr=strstr(readBuffer,"<!DOCTYPE "))!=NULL){
        strcpy( readBuffer, sstr );
    }
    if((sstr=strstr(readBuffer,"</html>"))!=NULL){
        strncpy(sstr+7,"\n",(BUFSIZ-strlen(readBuffer))+5);
    }
    fprintf(stdout,"%s",readBuffer);

    memset( readBuffer, 0 , BUFSIZ+1 );
}
```

PS: Actually, after reading the other response, I realize that you're making an even bigger mistake depending on stringA being a pointer to a BUFSIZ array after you have reassigned it to some other address (returned from the build query).

Comment: strlen() only counts till '\0', that never happens, thanks for trying to help though

Comment: Why not? If you read BUFSIZ bytes from the source into the buffer, where's the '\0' ?? Are you **guaranteed** the input will never be BUFSIZ or more bytes long? Note: the SIGSEGV you're reporting is almost certainly the result of a memory corruption and a buffer overrun is the fastest way to get there.

Comment: nope im not, you are right, but my code **fortunatly** was protected against that because of maxpacket size + good implementation of read(3)

Comment: Quick test... comment out the `while()` loop and run the test again. Still get a SIGSEGV?

Comment: no, it runs + terminates/exits normaly, even after i've corrected the `malloc(BUFSIZ+1)` + `memset( stringA, 0, BUFSIZ+1 )`

Comment: So... proves my point... your `while()` loop is overwriting memory because you are depending on a null terminator being at the end of the buffer when there is nothing guaranteeing that. Also, note, you set the `sizeof( stringA` ) which is the size of a pointer, not the buffer. You are walking through memory. See my suggested changes, implement and see if they fix it.

Comment: i get this now instead of a segfault **does printf the entire webpage as supposed** but in the end gives  `Inconsistency detected by ld.so: dl-fini.c: 195: _dl_fini: Assertion 'ns != 0 || i == nloaded' failed!`, while gdb says `Program exited with code 0177.`

Comment: Okay -- made a new edit based on the realization that you have a bigger problem (compliments of the post from Lucas)

Comment: Glad it sorted out for you. Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

And the size of the buffer allocated to stringA isn't BUFSIZ. After all it receives the address of the buffer allocated in build_get_query, which could be even smaller than BUFSIZ.
I don't know why you use stringA=malloc(BUFSIZ) and in the next instruction you change the stringA pointer to another buffer. There are many memory leaks there.

Comment: i did that on an attempt not to allocate more strings, so i reused stringA

Comment: but you replaced the pointer to the BUFSIZ memory block allocated to `stringA` with a pointer to the `malloc()` value assigned to query, which I'll bet money is way smaller than BUFSIZ. See the edit to my answer for the fix to that.

Comment: @lucas thanks for your input, because of you k-scott-piel solved my bad memory usage